# Синтаксический разбор предложения "Я буду рада видеть вас снова"?

Tags: синтаксический-разбор, сказуемые, обстоятельство

Подскажите, пожалуйста, вид и состав сказуемого (какая в нем связка) и каким обстоятельством является наречие "снова".

Оно имеет значение "еще раз, опять". Можно ли его тогда считать обстоятельсвом времени и задать вопрос "когда"?

Answer (score 2):

***Я буду рада видеть вас снова.***

Предикативная основа – ***я буду рада видеть***. Это простое предложение (одна основа).

Сказуемое – ***буду рада видеть.*** Это составное глагольное сказуемое, модальная связка "буду рада". Глагольная связка "буду" в форме будущего времени является вспомогательной, она выражает грамматические признаки глагола. Основной глагол  ***видеть*** в форме инфинитива.

Наречие ***снова*** является обстоятельством, но вид его определить сложно, так что без необходимости его лучше не называть вообще. Хотя, строго говоря,  это не обстоятельство времени, но условно можно задать вопрос "когда" (такой вопрос подойдет лучше других).

**Справочная информация**

Здесь есть интересный  материал о видах обстоятельств:
https://studopedia.ru/3_79396_obstoyatelstvo-vidi-obstoyatelstv-i-sposobi-ih-virazheniya.html

**Обстоятельство** – это второстепенный член предложения, выражающий различные обстоятельственные значения.

**Значение**. Значение характеристики действия, признака со стороны качества, количества, различных условий протекания и проявления их. И т.д.

11. **Обстоятельства обстановки** (ситуации). В какой обстановке? В какой ситуации? Выделяют недавно, обозначают состояние лица, природы, среды и т.п. Традиционно их рассматривают как обстоятельства места, времени, условия. Например: в дыму, при шуме, на солнышке.
12. **Модальные обстоятельства.** Обозначают соотносимость признака с действием. Например: день действительно выдался солнечным. Обыкновенно я ездил в пером классе. По своем семантике они близки к вводным словам, но в отличие от них примыкают к сказуемому и являются членами предложения.

Чтобы определить, к **какой группе** относится обстоятельство, можно сделать следующее: 1) превратить в придаточное предложение; 2) добавить уточняющий член предложения; 3) расширить однородными членами предложения.

Бывают обстоятельства, которые **невозможно отнести ни к одной из указанных групп,** к которым невозможно задать вопрос: Приходи ко мне обязательно. Относят к **модальным** обстоятельствам.